# Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred when calling function

Tags: swift, generics

I have a function :

```
static func create<T>(userId: Int, streamId: Int, isPushStream: Bool = false, delegateToController controller: T? = nil) -> ShowUserInfoVC where T: UIViewController, T: ShowUserInfoVCDelegate {
    let showUserInfoVC = ShowUserInfoVC()
    showUserInfoVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    showUserInfoVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    showUserInfoVC.delegate = controller
    showUserInfoVC.userId = userId
    showUserInfoVC.streamId = streamId
    showUserInfoVC.isPushStream = isPushStream
    return showUserInfoVC
}
```

When I call:

```
let vc = ShowUserInfoVC.create(userId: id, streamId: id)
```

It says error:

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you call a function, the swift compiler must be able to infer every generic parameter.

If you pass `nil`, the generic parameter cannot be inferred, because it is compatible with every optional type.

You must tell it that this `nil` is of a certain type. You can do this by casting:

```
let vc = ShowUserInfoVC.create(userId: id, streamId: id, delegateToController: nil as SomeType?)
```

As Alexander in the comments suggested, `SomeType?.none` and `Optional<SomeType>.none` work as well

where `SomeType` is a type that satisfies the constraints.

That sucks, doesn't it?

A workaround for this is to create an overload of `create` that takes only 3 arguments, and have that call `create` as shown above.

For example:

```
static func create<T>(userId: Int, streamId: Int, isPushStream: Bool = false) -> ShowUserInfoVC where T: UIViewController, T: ShowUserInfoVCDelegate {
    create(userId: userId, streamId: streamId, isPushStream: isPushStream, delegateToController: nil as DummyController?)
}

// private/fileprivate "dummy" class
private class DummyController: UIViewController, ShowUserInfoVCDelegate {
    // implement methods with stubs
}
```

Comment: If I want to delegate some ViewController, like AViewController, BViewController.... Your approach is not good.

Comment: @Khuong I see you trying to not pass an argument to the last parameter, did you not? That will use the `nil` default value as you specified. Right?

Comment: Yes, some ViewController call that static function don't want the delegation.

Comment: @Khuong If you want to delegate to a view controller then pass an instance to it! If not, call the other overload.

Comment: Ok, just pass an argument to the last parameter, and if the ViewController don't want to implement some function of protocol, just extension that protocol like `someFunction() { }`.